# JMESPATH does not contains/starts_with

Tags: jmespath

```
{
  "data": {
    "edges": [
      {
        "node": {
          "id": "ABC12345",
          "tags": [
            {
              "name": "Dummy"
            },
            {
              "name": "HelloT"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "node": {
          "id": "XYZ123",
          "tags": [
            {
              "name": "Testing"
            },
            {
              "name": "Test"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to use jmespath on the above json: Return the node if the **node.tags[].name** that does not **contain** any **Hello*** (starts_with)

I have tried the following

```
(data.edges[].node)[? (tags[])[? !starts_with(name, 'Hello')  ] ]
```

However it is still returning the first node because it has the tags.name == 'Dummy'

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same; turns out wrapping the command (in your case, `starts_with`) in parentheses should do the trick.

`(data.edges[].node)[? (tags[])[? !(starts_with(name, 'Hello')) ] ]`